# How to make app give timely notifications in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on a project that went open source. The project is a GPS based strategy game where players attack eachother using missiles.

The app is supposed to send notifications to the user's phone when they are under attack. The problem is, right now the app uses workmanager to send a request to the game server once every 15 minutes (the limitation imposed by android) to check whether their player is under attack, which completely misses the attack *most of the time.* Truly an unreliable method.

I notice that apps like Discord, Facebook Messenger, etc, are able to send notifications the instant a new message is sent without fail. How do they do this? Is this something I can use for my app?

Answer (score 0):

You use push messaging (like Firebase Cloud Messaging) to push alerts from the server to the client when one occurs.